# MySQL port 3306 vs 3307 Differences

Tags: mysql

This is more of a general Question regarding MySQL Database connections. I am looking to get clarification regarding the difference between MySQL's port 3306 (default) and port 3307. I haven't been able to find a lot of information truly explaining the differences. Is there a difference beyond just another port that MySQL can listen to? Is one port suppose to be more secure than the other? Do they both use TCP secured connections?

All help is appreciated.

Also, please let me know if I am asking this question in the wrong place. Normally I don't ask generalized questions...

Comment: MySQL (or most/all other processes) can listen on just about [any port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking)) (0-65535) though ports below 1024 are privileged and require special permissions (usually root/admin). There is no difference in port 3306, 3307 or 8279 for that matter other than that 3306 is the default port for MySQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, all ports above 1024 (0-1024 are [priviliged ports](https://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html)) are equal, and the default ones are just a convention.

**Security:**
Bots roam the internet trying to find out possible weak points. Changing a port is quite a weak countermeasure for this, and very trivial for an actual motivated attacker.

Therefore, strong passwords, white-listing ip's to access the mysql applications and other measures should be used.

Comment: I am not having security issues with the current port. I actually asked because I am trying to test a new app claiming to require SSL connectivity to the MySQL Databases, and I am not sure what they mean by that, as the connection methods are different.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/building-with-encrypted-connection-support.html

Comment: Will need more information, I think adding ssl support is not connected to any port. Encrypted connections can run on any port

Comment: Thank you for the info, this is helping a lot, especially the link. This is what the app was discussing.

Comment: "Security: Bots roam the internet trying to find out possible weak points. Changing a port is quite a weak countermeasure for this"... that's why some admin choose to blocks the port to MySQL and use port knocking to open the port off MySQL for one ip.or the knocking ip.... Or better to use a SSH tunnel as requirement for the MySQL connection.

Comment: Having port 3306 open at all to the general internet is a huge liability. At the absolute least lock this down to a whitelisted set of IPs. Even better, use an SSH tunnel to connect.

Comment: @tadman as far as ports go, changing the port number will provide very little added security.  Added your input to the answer though

Comment: @Skarlinski Changing port numbers makes it marginally more difficult for attackers to find, it's true. The best security is not having the port open in the first place. A closed or firewalled port can't be probed.

Comment: To add more information, the port is locked down to allow only whitelisted IPs

Answer (score 2):

There's absolutely no difference between one port or another.

A port is just a number you give to a software on the network to listen on. 
No rules are pre-define on it, it's up to you to define them.

Comment: That was what I thought... I asked because I am trying to test a new app claiming to require SSL connectivity to the MySQL Databases, and I am not sure what they mean by that, as the connection methods are different. Can rules be set up on a port that would somehow require SSL?

Comment: There isn't any port which require SSL, it's again up to you to configure SSL on a port.